# Keeping the session alive in python

Tags: python, session, download, keep-alive

I am experimenting with capatcha images. I have a capatcha.php in my local host which will generate an image and that image will be put into the form

Here is my python code to get the image, extract the text in it and send them back to the form. And finally save the resulting form as html.

```
import os
import requests

p = requests.session()
q = p.get('http://localhost/dhiraagu/Capatcha.php')
with open('data/a.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(q.content)
os.system("tesseract C:\\Users\\Aiman\\Desktop\\Wataniya\\data\\a.png C:\\Users\\Aiman\\Desktop\\Wataniya\\data\\a")
with open("data\\a.txt") as cap:
    capData = cap.read()
print("Capatcha line:"+capData)
num = input("Please enter the number :")
payload = {
    'Code': capData,
    'q': num
}

url = "http://localhost/dhiraagu/index.php"
r = p.post(url, data=payload)


with open("data\\log.html", "w") as file:
    log = file.write(r.text)
```

But this is now working. I don't see the problem here. :confused:

**EDIT**
I have solved that by putting the code inside a `with requests.session() as s:` line :D

And will there be any problem if I don't send the 'header'? ...

Answer (score 0):

you need to save cookies, and then send them to server. 
I've example for getting cookies, but not hard to extend this to send them:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import http.cookiejar
>>> cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
>>> opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
>>> urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
>>> reply = urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.com")
>>> for cookie in cj:
...     print(cookie)
```

and here is your cookies :)

Comment: I have actually done this by putting everything in side a `with requests.session() as s:`
And it worked fine :D